# vi sequence number generation

Tags: regex, vi, vim

I need to create a file in `vi` with this pattern. Is there a way to auto generate these lines using the first line

```
run 1 end
run 2 end
run 3 end
run 4 end
run 5 end
run 6 end
```

I can always do this in excel and then convert it to a text file and then switch to `vi`, but wanted to know if there a way to do it in `vi` so that I don't have to switch back to excel

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`:help ctrl-a`

^a increments the number under the cursor, which you can use in a macro.  For your case, assuming you have the first line and the cursor is on it:

```
qaYpw^aq4@a
```

Should do the trick.  This is the technique outlined in the help pages, modified with `w` to move the cursor forward to the number.  Breaking it down:

`qa` start recording a macro in register `a`

`Y` yank the current line

`p` put the yank buffer below the current position and move to column 1 of the new row

`w` move forward one word (to the number)

`^a` increment the number

`q` stop recording the macro

`<count>@a` apply the macro <count> times

Another technique is to use an external tool.  For example, if you already have the line and the cursor is on it:

```
!!awk '1;{for(i=0;i<5;i++){$2+=1; print}}'
```

Comment: `qa` starts recording
`Yp` yanks and pastes
`w` moves the cursor to the next word
The rest I don't follow

Comment: `^a` means to hold the ctrl key and hit `a`.  This gets awkward if you are running in a tmux and/or screen session that is stealing the keystroke.

Comment: This works. I took `^a` as `^` `a`. Now I get that this is `CTRL+A`. Thanks

Comment: The `awk` command also works. Could be please explain that as well. Thanks again. I understand the for loop and I guess `$2+=1`  gives the increment as 1. `print` prints it. what does `1` in the beginning do

Comment: The `w` isn't actually needed. `^A` will look ahead from the cursor position to the first number that is found, so it would work fine if used at the start of the line.

Comment: @arunmoezhi The leading `1` is to print the original line before incrementing the second column.

Answer (score 3):

`:put!=map(range(1,6),'\"run \".v:val.\" end\"')`

Answer (score 2):

William's answer is very nice. I'll post another solution (it's a little more complicated), suppose you already have the first line

```
Y6P
:let g:I=1
:%g/\d/s/\d/\=g:I/|let g:I=g:I+1
```

- let allows you to assign variables
- g runs a global command
- \d matches the number in the line
- s is for substitute
- \d is because you are going to write a number
- \= is replace expression (see: `:help sub-replace-\=`)
- g:I is the variable we are replacing in the expression and let increments the variable g:I